# ruby write all lines of puts in file?

Tags: ruby

I have my file

ppp.txt

```
mmm;2;nsfnjd;pet;
sadjjasjnsd;6;gdhjsd;pet;
gsduhdssdj;3;gsdhjhjsd;dog;
```

I need to write

```
nsfnjd
gsdhjhjsd
```

I use this code but only print the last line "gsdhjhjsd"
I dont know what is doing wrong

```
 File.open("ppp.txt", "r")  do |fi|
  fi.readlines.each do |line|
    parts = line.chomp.split(';')


    if parts[1].to_i < 4

 puts parts[2]
 File.open("testxx.txt", "w+") do |f|
  f. puts parts[2]
end

    end

  end
end
```

Please help me

Comment: Please indent your code with two-spaces and use sensible spacing.

Comment: You source file looks like a CSV file with `;` separators. It might be much easier to use the [Ruby's CSV library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) instead of handling the file and the string manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file using append mode, 'a+' instead of write mode 'w+', which overwrites the file, as the open command is called inside a loop.

Or open the write file prior to looping the lines of the read file.

Answer (score 1):

open the file descriptor outside the loop

```
fo = File.open("testxx.txt","w+")
File.open("ppp.txt", "r")  do |fi|
  fi.readlines.each do |line|
    parts = line.chomp.split(';')
    fo.puts parts[2] if parts[1].to_i < 4
  end
end
fo.close()
```

**NOTE:** Need to explicitly close `fo`, but file open with block; ruby close the file automatically (`fi` case).